# Batch Script - Run Every 30min Between 5AM-10PM

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation, scheduled-tasks

Below is the snip of a Batch script scheduled for daily execution via Window's task scheduler. However, the time interval option isn't available in the scheduler.

```
echo open <hostname> >tmp.txt
echo <username> >>tmp.txt
echo <password> >>tmp.txt
:: Some Work
echo quit>>tmp.txt

ftp -i -s:tmp.txt
```

Need some guidance on making the script run between 5AM-10PM, every 30mins, using batch commands.

Comment: check [schtasks](https://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html)

Comment: Check CronW http://cronw.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @npocmaka Firstly, thanks for the help.

This is what I have so far. It needs to be run daily between 5AM-10PM at hourly intervals.
`SCHTASKS /Create /TN runScript /ST 05:00 /SC Hourly /MO 1 /TR <loc>/script.bat /ET 22:00`
But this just runs for current day, and not on daily basis.
Also, if the local machine isnt turned on by 5AM, say 6:55AM, I still need to run from 7AM till 10PM.